# Why $\mu-x_i =0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Given $$\sum_i (V^{-1}\mu-V^{-1}x_i)=0$$ where $V$ is the variance matrix from [multivariate normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution), $\mu$ and $x_i$ are vectors. How can we conclude $\sum_i\mu=\sum_i x_i$?

**Update:**

In this question, $V$ inverse exists same as saying $V$ is nonsigular or the columns of $V$ are linearly indepdent. **I suspect the nonsigular matters here.** If we replace $V^{-1}$ with another matrix $A$, where $A$ not necessary nonsigular,can we still have $\sum_i\mu=\sum_i x_i$ given $\sum_i (A\mu-Ax_i)=0$?

Comment: $\mu$ usually denotes the mean of the vectors $x_i$, is that not the case here?

Comment: Correct, $\mu$ is the mean defined in multivariate normal distribution. @Rahul

Comment: For your second question, have you tried the case where $A$ is the zero matrix?  (it's the most singular matrix in the world :).

Comment: That's not what I asked. If $\mu$ is the mean of $x_i$, then $\mu = \frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ and it immediately follows that $\sum_i \mu = n\mu = \sum_i x_i$. If $\mu$ is not the mean of the $x_i$ but is the mean of some unrelated multivariate normal distribution, then see Erick's comment.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've got what you mean. @Rahul

Comment: Thanks, Erick. In general, given any matrix A, can we obtain $\sum_i \mu = \sum_i x_i$? I suspect the answer is no, but having difficulties to understand the reasons behind. @ErickWong

Comment: @Logan Please read my comment.  In order for something to be true "in general" it must first be true for any specific matrix.  So ask yourself whether it's true for $A=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give it a try to answer this question in another perspective.

Let's say $A$ is any matrix, we have
$$\sum_i(A\mu-Ax_i)=A\sum_i(\mu-x_i)=Ab=0$$
where $b=\sum_i(\mu-x_i)$.

In order to obtain $Ab=0$,

1) Best case scenario, $A$ is a non-singular matrix or columns of $A$ are linearly independent, under this situation, $b$ must be $0$. (only this case guarantee that $\sum_i \mu = \sum_i x_i$)

2) As suggested by Erick, doesn't matter what values $b$ take, letting $A$ be a zero matrix also gives $Ab=0$.

3) Additionally, there could be some $A$ that not non-singular or zero but also satisfies $Ab=0$, which depending on values of $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Just multiply both sides by $V$.

$$0 = V \sum_i (V^{-1} \mu - V^{-1} x_i) = \sum_i V (V^{-1} \mu - V^{-1} x_i) = \sum_{i} (\mu - x_i) = \sum_i \mu - \sum_i x_i $$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Robert! There just another variation of  this question came to my mind, I've added it in UPDATES. If you don't mind, could you give some suggests also.